# PHP Sessionhandling/Specific values from $_SERVER constant per session?

Tags: php, session

Is it save to assume that the values of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` are constant during a php-session? (As long as just using `session_start()` and not somehow persist and load "gone" sessions, of course)

Why do I want to know?

I'm tracing these values for each created session anyway, mainly for statistics. But there are usecases where I explicitly need to store this values (i.e. email subscription and confirmation) which may ocure "sometimes" during a session. So I'd prefer just referencing the already stored "tracing values", and not assigning and storing them again.

Answer (score 0):

The connecting IP address `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will always be available. Anything else is provided via headers in the web request and can easily be changed or not be present at all.

So in answer to your question - no it is not safe to presume this (with the exception of IP).

Comment: Ok thank you so far...but will `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` be unique per php session? Stupid example, but might point out my question: Opening the website in a webbrowser at home, then taking the laptop to the neighbour and continuing to browse in the same window/browser instance after connecting to the neighbours network. Will php drop the session on reconnect? Closing the browser i.e. starts a new session in any way. For the other fields  i guess my question is rather philosophical: Storing once works out for "the good guys", storing directly everytime wont help for "the bad guys" neither...